# error: syntax error at end of input - Nodejs and PostgreSQL (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, heroku

When the user enters the website on the first time he gets a special string assigned to him. I am saving that string in a row that contains the user's IP as well. So when the user enters the website I want to query the DB and ask if it finds his IP in the table. I get a syntex error altough when I use the CLI it works find and returns t if the IP exists or f if it's not, as it should be.

The code:

```
let thisIP = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
    req.connection.remoteAddress ||
    req.socket.remoteAddress ||
    (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null);

client.query("SELECT exists(SELECT 1 from registrations WHERE ip='" + thisIP + "'",
    (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(res.rows[0]);
    });
```

The error:

```
error: syntax error at end of input
```

Comment: where is exits parenthesis!? I think you missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing parenthesis of the exists function.